# How to sum integer item in List<object>?

Tags: c#, linq

How to find sum integer number in code?

```
List<object> lst = new List<object> { "c#", 12, "Simi", 236.5, 17, "Asp.net", 98 };
lst.Where(c => c is int).ToList().Sum();

lst.Where(c => c is string).ToList().Max(d => d.ToString().Length);
```

Comment: Can you please state an example input __and output__ and explain with some more details? I would be somewhat surprised if you really want to exclude any non-`int` numbers from your sum, but that's what you ask right now

Comment: Why call `ToList()` before `Sum` and `Max`?

Comment: Preempting another question:   if there are no strings in the list, `.Max()` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. I recommend replacing it with `lst.OfType<string>().DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty).Max(d => d.Length);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the other answers supplied are effective enough, I would like to supply a thorough answer to assist at more than just the current syntactical level of C#. For example; `Linq` wasn't available [prior to 3.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

***`IS` Keyword***

> Checks if an object is compatible with a given type, or (starting with [C# 7.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions)) tests an expression against a pattern.

***LINQ***

> Many of the concepts that LINQ has introduced were originally tested in Microsoft's [Cω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%CF%89) research project. LINQ was released as a major part of [.NET Framework 3.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_3.5) on November 19, 2007.

***Primal Sum***

A primitive version to do it all in one shot would be to write a method that returns a `double` value but accepts a `List<object>` value. The reason I chose `double` is due to it's incredibly high maximum range of [±5 * 10^-324 - ±1.7 * 10^308](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double). The `double` type is capable of achieving the sum of all values provided, and the risk for overflow is reduced, but not eliminated. Even `double` has a minimum and maximum value. I've tried to account for this; however, all I can do is let the exception bubble back up to the implementation.

```
public double SumNumericsFromListOfObjects(List<object> objects) {
    double sum = 0;
    foreach (object o in objects) {
        double val = 0;
        if (double.TryParse(o.ToString(), out val)
            sum += val;
    }
    return sum;
}

// Usage:
private void DoSomeCoolStuff() {
    List<object> myObjects = new List<object>();
    object[] objects = new object[] { 12, 32, 1, 9, "5", "18", 3.14, "9.9", false };
    myObjects.AddRange(objects);

    double sumOfObjects = SumNumericsFromListOfObjects(myObjects);
    int iSum = 0;
    long lSum = 0;
    if (sumOfObjects < int.MaxValue)
        iSum = (int)sumOfObjects;
    else if (sumOfObjects > int.MaxValue && sumOfObjects < long.MaxValue)
        lSum = (long)sumOfObjects;
    else
        // You just have to use the double type at this point.
}
```

The above example should handle most cases from the object list. Granted the original post clearly states objects of type `int` should be summed and doesn't really specify whether `string` values or `double` values should be accounted for, nor how they should be handled. I personally believe that it would be best to handle all cases; therefore, since `string` values can be parsed to `double` values if they meet certain criteria and doubles can be converted back to integers (assuming their values do not exceed the max value for `int`), I decided to sum at the `double` level and then convert back to integer at the implementation of the method to ensure no numeric values are missed. The above method should be able to handle the following [types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types):

`byte`: 0 - 255

`sbyte`: -128 - 127

`short`: -32768 - 32767

`ushort`: 0 - 65535

`int`: -2147483648 - 2147483647

`uint`: 0 - 4294967295

`long`: -9 * 10^18 - 9 * 10^18

`ulong`: 0 - 1.8 * 10^19

`float`: ±1.5 * 10^-45 - ±3.4 * 10^38

`double`: ±5 * 10^-324 - ±1.7 * 10^308

`decimal`: ±10^-28 - ±7.9 * 10^28

***Extension Methods***

Another quick and efficient route if you find yourself frequently adding up values from a list of objects would be to add [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to the `List<object>` type. Keep in mind, this method also has the potential to overflow the minimum and maximum values for the type the arithmetic is being performed on.

```
internal class Extensions {
    public static double Sum(this List<object> objects) {
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (object o in objects) {
            double val = 0;
            if (double.TryParse(o.ToString(), out val))
                sum += val;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

// Usage:
double sum = myObjects.Sum();
```

If anyone feels I left out some useful information, or maybe did something incorrectly here, please feel free to comment and inform me so that I can update this post to better educate future readers.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest changing:

```
lst.Where(c => c is int).ToList().Sum();
```

to:

```
var sum = lst.OfType<int>().Sum();
```

`OfType<int>` will ensure that only integers are considered (e.g. strings will be ignored), and `Sum` will sum them up.

Comment: For the downvoters, feel free to leave feedback about how to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

`lst.Sum(c => c is int ? (int)c : 0)`